# how to make an array of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

how would you write an array of values to other array. In instance, I have a list of IPs and list of requests. I want to have something like [{ip1, request1}, {ip2, request2}, ....].

It's how I would do it, but sure **obj** will change every time and array will have all the time the same values.

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    Object[] obj = new Object[2];

    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){

        obj[0] = ipList.get(i).toString();
        obj[1] = requestList.get(i);

        array.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){
    Object[] obj = {ipList.get(i).toString(), requestList.get(i)};

    array.add(obj);
}
```

Also consider creating a new class for `obj`.  (I do not know what it should be called because you did not say what it is for.)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the line where you create obj into the loop...

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){
    Object[] obj = new Object[2];

    obj[0] = ipList.get(i).toString();
    obj[1] = requestList.get(i);

    array.add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with a LinkedHashMap

```
  Map map = new LinkedHashMap();
  for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++){

    map.put( ipList.get(i).toString(), requestList.get(i) );

    }
```

Comment: That will only work if the IP addresses are unique (the OP did not specify this.)